# influx: merging large database with select into fails. Alternatives?

Tags: docker, import, influxdb, influxql

influxdb 1.8.10

I have 2 databases which was originally one, but due to hardware limitations,I had to move to a new system and just started a new database there.

now i've upgraded to a new system and wants to merge these two again.
I've restored the backups of both into a seperate docker instance in two db. energypre2021 and energycombined(which has the data beyond 2021)

if I use
 `influx  -database=energycombined   -execute 'SELECT * INTO energypre2021..:MEASUREMENT FROM /.*/ GROUP BY *'`
in the docker container, i just get kicked out of the docker instance without any messages and no merged db.

the log just says this

```
ts=2022-09-08T22:30:10.118858Z lvl=info msg="Open store (end)" log_id=0cooRaaG000 service=store trace_id=0cooRa~0000 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=end op_elapsed=4042.491ms
```

any tips on how to effectively merge both db's? I am willing to merge one table at a time if needed.

influxdb 1.8.10
64GBRam +1TB SSD should be enough power for this stuff me thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably export the database from the two instances separately and then import them one by one.

Step 1: export the database from the two instances

```
influx_inspect export -compress -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data  -waldir /var/lib/influxdb/wal -out /root/1.gz

influx_inspect export -compress -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data  -waldir /var/lib/influxdb/wal -out /root/2.gz
```

Step 2: and then you can import these two files one by one:

```
influx -import -compressed=true -path=/root/1.gz
influx -import -compressed=true -path=/root/2.gz
```

See more details [here on the export](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/influx_inspect/#export) and [there on the import](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/shell/#import-data-from-a-file-with--import).

Comment: this answer helped me to the final solution (listed below)

Answer (score 1):

I actually did an export -portable of both instances
`influxd backup  -portable    -database energy    /mnt/backup/pre2020`

`influxd backup  -portable    -database energy    /mnt/backup/newestdata`

then I restore the instance with the least data (newestdata) in one empty influx instance. . `influxd restore    -portable    -database energy /mnt/backup/newestdata` and export a copy of this `influx_inspect export   -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data/ -waldir /var/lib/influxdb/wal/ -out /mnt/backup/newestdata.gz`

then i drop that instance and restore the export with the most data `influxd restore    -portable    -database energy /mnt/backup/pre2020`

and then import the export
`influx -import -compressed=true -path=/mnt/backup/newestdata.gz`
then I import both instances-backups one by one in one empty influx instance.